# make handler for windowbuilder class in eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, handler, rcp, windowbuilder

I used windowbuilder and swt designer to develop a shell with some labels, text and bottoms. I can run it as a java application. I added that class to my eclipse RCP project and linked it to a menu in RCP. when I run the RCP and click the menu, I receive an error that **There is no handler to execute for command...**

the question is how I can make handler for my classes which are built from windowbuilder?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problems after I tried Windowbuilder installed on the Juno CDT version of eclipse. Windowbuilder is new... Try using Juno Java, that comes with WB by default, it worked fine for me...